# How to parse nested json and write in Redshift?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

I have a following json structure like this:

```
{
    "firstname": "A",
    "lastname": "B",
    "age": 24,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "123",
        "city": "San Jone",
        "state": "CA",
        "postalCode": "394221"
    },
    "phonenumbers": [
        { "type": "home", "number": "123456789" }
        { "type": "mobile", "number": "987654321" }
    ]
}
```

I need to copy this json from S3 to a Redshift table.

I am currently using copy command with a path file but it loads array as a single column.

I wanted the nested array to be parsed and the table should like this:

```
firstname|lastname|age|streetaddress|city   |state|postalcode|type|number
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
A        | B      |24 |123          |SanJose|CA   |394221    |home|123456789
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
A        | B      |24 |123          |SanJose|CA   |394221    |mob|987654321
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do use nested JSON paths by making use of [JSON path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-json-jsonpaths) files. However, this does not work with the multiple phone number types.

If you **can modify** the dataset to have multiple records (one for mobile, one for home) then your file would look similar to the below.

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$.firstname",
        "$.lastname",
        "$.venuestate",
        "$.age",
        "$.address.streetAddress",
        "$.address.city",
        "$.address.state",
        "$.address.postalCode",
        "$.phonenumbers[0].type",
        "$.phonenumbers[0].number"
    ]
}
```

If you are **unable to change the format** you will need to perform an ETL task upon load before it can be consumed by Redshift. For this you could use an event for creation of objects to trigger a Lambda function and then perform the ETL process for you before it loads into Redshift.